# A $k$-linear map $\sigma: k[x]\rightarrow k[x]$ with property $\sigma(fg)=f\sigma(g)+\sigma(f)g$ has representation $\sigma(f)=aD(f)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

A $k$-linear map $\sigma: k[x]\rightarrow k[x]$ with property $\sigma(fg)=f\sigma(g)+\sigma(f)g$ has a representation $\sigma(f)=aD(f)$, where $a\in k[x]$ is unique and $D(f)$ is the formal derivative of $f$.

How do I prove this?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a map is called a *derivation*. Notice that $D$ is a derivation by the linearity of the derivative and the product rule. First notice that if such an $a$ exists, then
$$
 a
 = a \cdot 1
 = a \cdot D(t)
 = \sigma(t).
$$
Therefore we define $a := \sigma(t)$. Next notice that
$$
 \sigma(1)
 = \sigma(1 \cdot 1)
 = 1 \cdot \sigma(1) + \sigma(1) \cdot 1
 = 2 \sigma(1),
$$
so $\sigma(1) = 0 = a D(1)$. So we already have have $\sigma(t^n) = a D(t^n)$ for $n = 0$ and $n = 1$.

Suppose that $\sigma(t^n) = a D(t^n)$ for some $n \geq 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
 \sigma(t^{n+1})
 &= \sigma(t \cdot t^n)
 = t \sigma(t^n) + \sigma(t) t^n
 = t a D(t^n) + a t^n \\
 &= a (D(t^n) t + t^n)
 = a (D(t^n) t + t^n D(t))
 = a \cdot D(t^{n+1}).
\end{align*}

This shows that $\sigma(t^n) = a D(t^n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By the linearity of $\sigma$ and $D$ it follows that $\sigma = aD$.

PS: Instead of induction we can also notice that for every two derivations $D_1$ and $D_2$ on a $k$-algebra $k[x]$ the set $\{p \in k[x] \mid D_1(p) = D_2(p)\}$ forms a unital subalgebra of $k[x]$. Taking $D_1 = \sigma$ and $D_2 = aD$ this subalgebra contains $x$ by construction of $a$, and therefore already all of $k[x]$.

More generally we can use this to show that a derivation of an $k$-algebra $A$ is uniquely determined by its values on generators of $A$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm disappointed that I wasn't able to do it myself :/ - but at least I thought of some of it :).